# json Time (hh:mm:ss) value return from php json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, json, jchartfx

I just want to ask if the returned data from my php json_encode is directly treated as "time" on my jquery, or do I have to format it in my jquery script ? Here:

[image]

I will be using this data on my jchartFX, I just wonder if this has been treated as "time" values or not . Because my chart displays: "No Data Available".I already made a data format but it seemed like not working.
Here's the entire code:
PHP

```
public function get_sample_data(){



   $data = $this->queries->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.datetimeRequested,'%M %d') AS `Date`,
                            SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(c.request_startckit))) AS `AVG CT`, 
                               SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(c.request_startckit))) AS `SUM CT`        
                        FROM request a
                        JOIN ckit b ON b.idRequest = a.idRequest
                        JOIN cycle_time c ON c.idCkit = b.idCKIT
                                ");
     echo json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

Jquery:

```
chart1 = new cfx.Chart();
chart1.getData().setSeries(2);

var xaxis = chart1.getAxisX();
xaxis.getLabelsFormat().setFormat(cfx.AxisFormat.Date);

var yaxis = chart1.getAxisY();
yaxis.getLabelsFormat().setFormat(cfx.AxisFormat.DateTime);
yaxis.getDataFormat().setCustomFormat("hh:mm:ss");
chart1.getDataGrid().setVisible(true);          
var series1 = chart1.getSeries().getItem(0);
var series2 = chart1.getSeries().getItem(1);
series1.setGallery(cfx.Gallery.Bar);
series2.setGallery(cfx.Gallery.Bar);

            $.ajax({
                url: $("#base_url").val() + "ajax/get_sample_data",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){    

                   chart1.setDataSource(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("an error occured");
                } 
            });

 var divHolder = document.getElementById('ChartDiv');
 chart1.create(divHolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you gave an example on how you will be using those values, that way we could see if you would need any kind of parsing. To answer your question, in your JSON response both of them are being treated as strings.

Comment: I will be using it on my jchartFX. Wait, I'll update my question.

Comment: I've never used jchartFX, but according to their documentation "a numeric field will be plotted against the Y axis by default while a field with string values may be used by the chart as labels" which means that in this case if it's treating all values as strings it will not find any data to plot in the Y axes so you may need some sort of parsing, this link might be of help: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jan/06/JavaScript-JSON-Date-Parsing-and-real-Dates Good luck! :)